# Ghostscript/Imagemagick is not working in Django

Tags: python, django, imagemagick, ghostscript, wand

I am working on a Django/Django REST framework based web application.
I am building an API that slice pdf to every page, and convert them to image. 
Here are some of my code.

```
   with Image(filename=os.path.join(tmp_dir, pdffilename)) as img:
        for i, page in enumerate(img.sequence):
            file = '%s-%d.jpg' % (imagefilename, i + 1)
            Image(page).save(filename=file)
            filelist.append(file)
```

but I am getting this error:

> DelegateError: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-26897HyfIoUTUbASw%d' '-f/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-26897y4uJPEzsfHCE' '-f/var/folders/kl/5qf5q4x50xj2rbdp8t2prsbh0000gn/T/magick-268970ovMV9WfGDbE'' (1) @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/292

I am using python 2.7.10 / Django 1.9. And, of course, installed Ghostscript(9.2.2) and imagemagick(6.9.9).
It seems app can't execute ghostscript.
I am not sure why this is not working. Would you like to help me? Any idea why this isn't working for me?

Comment: It seems like maybe you don;t have Ghostscript in the PATH environment variable. The error doesn't seem to specify a path for Ghostscript, so it will only manage to execute it if it can find the binary, which means it needs to be in $PATH. Note, if you want Ghostscript to produce one file per page you do not need to create 'n' single page PDF files and process them individually, you can hand Ghostscript the original multi-page PDF and ask it to produce 'n' single page PNG files. Its usually quicker that way.

Comment: @kens - Thanks for your quick response. I have a simple question. So you mean - it's PATH environment variable of the system? Ghostscript path is /usr/local/bin/gs , and I have /usr/local/bin in $PATH variable.

Comment: @kens - I've added ghostscript path in $PATH variable:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.22/bin/
But not working yet. And I tried to call "gs" in the console, and it works. I think it means system recognized ghostscript path.

Comment: @kens- one more question: I've moved debug point and got this error:
WandError: wand contains no images `MagickWand-0' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickGetImageSignature/6102
Would you like to explain me what does this error means?

Comment: Not a clue, I don't know anything about ImageMagick. I can't give you any other pointers either, if you can execute Ghostscript from the command prompt. The only other possibility is that the user you are running the web application as is using a different environment.